# Testing our IVR - Twilio send_digits

Tags: twilio, ivr

I am building a machine to bounce with our company's IVR. For that I need a degenerated IVR and specifically I wish to have it receiving a call and sending_digits to the IVR.

I could not figure out how to send_digits without first calling the other party.

Using python for this matter.

Can someone spill light on this?

Comment: Thanks philnash, it looks like an xml. Do I need to create xml or can I use a python command?

Comment: You can generate the XML with Python, check out the example code here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/play?code-sample=code-using-digits&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=6.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think you are asking how to receive a call on a Twilio number and play DTMF tones. If so, you can do that using the [`<Play>` TwiML element](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/play).

`<Play>` normally expects a URL that plays an audio file. However, you can also pass the [`digits` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/play#attributes-digits) which will direct Twilio to send the DTMF tones down the line.

You can add any digits you like as well as pauses using the `w` character. A single `w` will wait for half a second and you can use multiple in a row. For example this TwiML will direct Twilio to send the digits 123 then wait 1 second, then send 456, then end the call.

```xml
<Response>
  <Play digits="123ww456"/>
</Response>
```